# obtain image from microscope camera in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide

I want to obtain images from microscope Cmos Camera in my matlab
i've already installed the image acquisition toolbox and also installed usb camera and os generic video interface hardware support packages.
but the the camera us not appearing when i run "WEBCAMLIST" command, the camera is accessible with the software which comes with the microscope.

[I have attached the camera picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWdwi.jpg)

Comment: It is possible that the manufacturer prevented access by other software.

Comment: most scientific or industrial cameras do not show up as webcams. they come with proprietary software. contact the manufacturer and ask for support.